# What is the damage of end crystals to players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I own an anarchy server, so many people use [end crystals](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Crystal) to fight. My friend got one shot by one of the crystals recently, so I'm wondering how much damage a crystal actually does. I've made recipes for protection 10 armor, and the full set (should) give 96% damage reduction (at least to my understanding, 20 armor points = 80% damage reduction, and protection 10 = 80% damage reduction, so stacking multiplicatively will give 96% damage reduction).

I will stand in a spot that lets me take 100% exposure.

How much damage will I take, and how many crystals do I need to get myself blown up?

Comment: Note that total protection is capped at 20; there's no difference between full Protection V and full Protection X

Comment: I know, it's just how it is on my armor. If i'm not mistaken the total protection count caps at 80% dmg reduction.

Answer (score 10):

The explosion strength is 6, the same as a charged creeper, and I believe that damage per explosion strength is constant, not variable between the source of the explosion, so it should be 97 damage at 100% strength, so with armor that has 96% absorption, you should take 3.88 damage or 1.94 hearts. As for how many, with ten hearts, it will take five or six crystals as an estimation, probably five due to the rounding up or down of damage, but it could take six in total, just with you being *extremely* one-tap after the fifth.

Comment: Wouldn't Enchanted Golden Apples improve this since they give extra hearts? If it's an anarchy server, they're probably walking around with whole stacks of them...

Comment: It would, but he didn't say anything about them, and he's talking about suicide, so it's not like a trap or whatever.

Comment: Thanks! True, Enchanted Golden Apples do give (16 extra absorption?) and people always pay some (duped) netherite blocks for another bar of hearts. so 56HP, and at 100% strength, it would take 14 - 15 crystals (14.4) to kill a player. But I guess people use HoleESP and CrystalAura, so I'll spectate and let them figure it out

Comment: AND 20% resistance I.

Comment: @nick012000 NOTCH APPLES/GOLDEN APPLES ALSO GIVE REGEN FOR A FEW SECONDS

Answer (score 5):

The maximum damage on hardest difficulty given the end crystal's strength, comparable to a charged creeper is 127.5. 4% of 85 (100%-96% is 4%) is 2 1/2 hearts (rounding). Big_Chungus is correct damage from explosions is consistent, provided that a variety of variables are not changed. It would take 4 crystals to kill a player with maximum damage reduction.

Comment: End crystals and charged creepers pack a ***PUNCH***. 127.5 damage is nothing to laugh about, so keep your guard up at all times on hard difficulty, *and* they ***BRUTALIZE*** players with no armor on. But yes, Big Chungus is right, explosion strength is constant, so about 6 end crystals.

Answer (score 1):

End crystals do a whopping 127.5 damage on hard difficulty, which is the same as a charged creeper in the same difficulty, so with no armor, you would get one-shot ***instantly***, and with a full diamond set with max protection of every type, plus a notch apple, it would take about 8 end crystals to commit total suicide